# ORA-65096 Oracle error creating new user

Tags: oracle

i'm trying to create a user on SQL Devloper but I've got the ORA-65096 error, I've applied the solution found in the forum but it doesn't work with me

```
connect system/manager as sysdba
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
create user hopital identified by toor;
grant dba to pubs;
connect hopital/toor
```

but the result was this:

```
Erreur commençant à la ligne: 9 de la commande -
connect hopital/toor
Rapport d'erreur -
Echec de la connexion
  USER          = hopital
  URL           = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcl
  Message d'erreur = ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
Commit
```

so I followed a tutorial and created it in consol:
[image]

as you see, my user has been created but when I try to connect to it by SQL Develper it gave me error

I don't understand where is the problem, and which SID should I put in this connexion ?

thanks
[image]

Comment: Don't use the user name for `SID`. Use the `SID` for `SID`. But you should be using the service name ("Nom de service") anyway as the is the recommended way nowadays.  If you don't know the service name, connect through SQL\*Plus and run `select sys_context('userenv','service_name') from dual;`

Answer (score 1):

SID identifies the instance, not the user.

Use `orcl` for SID - based on your output.

This is not a solution, it is a cheap dirty hack:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;
```

You got the `ORA-65096` error, because you have a container database, and you tried to create a common user in the root container without the common user prefix.

[Introduction to the Multitenant Architecture](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/cdbovrvw.htm#CNCPT89234)

Comment: where should I execute this command "alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true;" ?

Comment: @devhicham Nowhere. That is not the solution.

Comment: so what is the cause of this error, please ?